# Load content into a div with same performance as an IFrame

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

Have a issue with performance while injecting a glob of content into a view page. The markup can get rather large. I did a test using an IFrame to load the content from a temp file and directly by setting the html and the performance is much better than using the jquery .load() or html(). However, everything has already been built around loading into a div and I am trying to avoid IFrame.

NOTE : I am making a hunch that there are some operations going on when injecting the content into a dom that you don't get when loading into an IFrame. Similar to if open a 2.5 mb html directly in the browser it loads almost instantly, meanwhile, loading 2.5 mb into a div using jquery doesn't offer the same performance.

Are there any tricks I could use that would allow .load() to perform better?

**Edited: Added code:**

The question is rather straight forward. I am getting a payload from an ajax call that is either a  url or raw html. I am then using either

`element.html(content)`

or

`element.load(content)`

based on whether the content is a url or markup.

When I change the element to an IFrame and then use either

`element.attr('src', content);`

or

```
element.contents().find('html').html(content);
```

The content loads much faster.

Comment: If you want performance, use [vanilla-js](http://vanilla-js.com/) instead of jQuery. Anyway, can you post a demo?

Comment: What's taking your performance down, the download or the injection? you should investigate this further... the solution might be simple .. or not

Comment: Hi thanks for the reply. I am receiving the response in roughly 3 seconds the rendering is taking 15-20 seconds. When I use an iframe the content is rendered in approx. 3-5 seconds.